# MultiBrowser testing Framework

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am new to Nunit and wondering if there is a simpler method to test in multibrowser. I am currently aware of 2 methods below

1. Using TestFixture[typeof(Drivers)] attribute for a class

The above method is not reliable when I need to test only on 1 browser and skip the other browsers

2. Using IEnumerable method in a class and using `Testcasesource(tyeof(""), methodname)` attribute for every Testcase.

I have around 80-90 test cases. So method 2 looks like a repetitive approach.

Is there any better approach for my Selenium tests?

Comment: You want to use one browser and skip others in debug mode, e.g. when you write tests?

Comment: not in debug mode. Every night we run on all browsers but during day we run only on one browser.(something like that)

Comment: Typo in method 1: should be [TestFixture(typeof(Drivers)] for correct syntax. This is the best method to minimize repetition. You should explain more why it is "not reliable" so that someone can formulate an answer.

Comment: @charile. I have around 10-15  test suites.test classes to run. When we no longer support a single browser(Lets say IE11). Then it is painful to change testfixtures for all 15 classes or if we want to add another browser

Comment: Could you use a `[TestFixtureSource]` attribute on each class, with a single list of browsers to run on?

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am not aware of     [TestFixtureSource] . I will try to implement in my test suite